How to send blob via resolve() and onResult()
As shown in the below posted code, in the method attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath, it invokes stream method which in turn calls fetch to communicate with the backend.
The log statements of stream method are as shown in the screen-shot attached below.
The problem is, despite the log statements of stream method indicate that there is a value assigned to the response object, however, the logs in attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath method show that the blob object passed to attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath method
is empty as shown in the last line of the output posted in the attached screen-shot below.
Why the reponse object passed back to attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath method is empty despite the logs indicate that it, indeed has value.
attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath:
attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath(nameOfGeoTIFF) {
    if (nameOfGeoTIFF) {
        if (typeof nameOfGeoTIFF === 'string') {

            this.#wsGeoTIFFStreamer = new WSGeoTIFFStreamer(nameOfGeoTIFF);
            this.#wsGeoTIFFStreamer.setRequestOptionsParams();
            this.#wsGeoTIFFStreamer.stream(result => {
                this.#msg = JSON.stringify({msg:verboseTag + 'xcx attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath().',
                    result: result.blob,
                    result_: JSON.stringify(result),
                    type: typeof result,
                });
                console.log(this.#msg);
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.#msg = JSON.stringify({msg:verboseTag + 'xcx attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath().',
                    result: res,
                    type: typeof res,
                });
                console.log(this.#msg);
                new GeoTIFF({
                    sources: [
                      {
                        blob: res,
                        overviews: ['https://openlayers.org/data/raster/no-overviews.tif.ovr'],
                      },
                    ],
                });
            });

        }
    }
}

stream:
stream(onResult) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const ws = `${endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_LOCAL_HOST_3000.description}${endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_PATH.description}${BackendWssConstants.CONST_WS_GEOTIFF_STREAMER.description}/${this.#geoTIFFFileName}`;

        await fetch(ws, this.#requestOptions)
        .then(async response =>  {
            const b = await response.blob()
            console.log('xcx response: ', response)
            console.log('xcx Response status:', response.status);
            console.log('xcx Response headers:', response.headers);
            console.log('xcx blob: ', b)

            resolve(b);
            onResult(b);
        })
    });
}

screen-shot


The blob is not empty. {} and object are how JSON.stringify converts a blob and its type to text. Some code to run a demonstration in a browser console:
const res = new Blob(["I'm a tiff"]);
console.log( res, JSON.stringify({res, type: typeof res}));

Solution: remove JSON.stringify from the debug code.

I highly recommend removing new Promise from the stream method to make it read more like:
stream() {
  const ws = `${endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_LOCAL_HOST_3000.description}${endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_PATH.description}${BackendWssConstants.CONST_WS_GEOTIFF_STREAMER.description}/${this.#geoTIFFFileName}`;

  // return the promise from response.blob():

  return fetch(ws, this.#requestOptions)
  .then( response => response.blob()); 
}

This is assuming that,
unless onResult is an external function, its use is not needed.

would you please tell me what did you mean by onResult is an extenal function

Sorry, I actually meant some kind of callback function outside the class of the methods that needed to be notified of any tiff image data received, say if the posted code were a cut down version of something much more complicated. Hopefully not in this case :-)
